# Python Selenium Webdriver - Handling mouseover on Instagram

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, instagram

I'm creating an Instagram Unfollow Tool. The code usually works, but occasionally Instagram will show the information of some user (as if I hovered over that user) and cause my code to stop running because it obscures the buttons that I need to click in order to unfollow a user.

It's easier to understand with an example:

[image]

How can I edit my code to make the mouseover information go away (is there a way to turn off these mouseover effects)?

My code:

```
for i in range(num_following):
    following = self.browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[5]/div/div/div[2]/ul/div/li[{}]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/span/a".format(i))
    following_username = following.get_attribute("title")   
    
    if following_username not in followers:
        # Unfollow account
        following_user_button = self.browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[5]/div/div/div[2]/ul/div/li[{}]/div/div[2]/button".format(i))
        following_user_button.click()

        unfollow_user_button = self.browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[6]/div/div/div/div[3]/button[1]")
        unfollow_user_button.click()

        print("You've unfollowed {}.".format(following_username))
```

The error I get:

selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: Element  is not clickable at point (781,461) because another element  obscures it

Comment: May you insert your code snippet in the question or else we have a hard time understanding the real issue. For example, why is your cursor even on this spot? Sending a `.click()` or e.g. `driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, Y)") ` with Selenium shouldn't move your mouse, hence why is the cursor there in the first place?

Comment: @J.M.Arnold I've added the code. I don't actually see a cursor on the screen, but the popup that appears is the same one that would appear if I hovered over the username with my cursor. Usually I'll be able to unfollow several accounts before the popup appears.

Comment: I tried it, and once again my cursor doesn't move, hence no popup magically appears? Moreover, even if there was one, you still could click the `Following` button as tried on Selenium with `Google Chrome WebDriver 87.0.4280.88`.

Comment: @J.M.Arnold I don't know why it's not working for me then. I get the following error: "selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: Element is not clickable at point (781,461) because another element obscures it". I just added a GIF to my question to show what it looks like. (While running the program, I don't move my cursor at all.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the element `unfollow_user_button = self.browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[6]/div/div/div/div[3]/button[1]")` you want to execute `.click()` on is blocked by a temporary or permanent overlay.

In such cases you either can wait with `ExplicitWait` and `ExplicitConditions` till said blocking element has vanished - though this shouldn't work in this specific case as to my knowledge the popup remains if nothing is done. Another approach is to send the click **directly** to the element by using the `JavascriptExecutor`:

```
#Find the element - by_xpath or alike
unfollow_user_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("XPATH")

#Sending the click via JavascriptExecutor
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", unfollow_user_button)
```

**Note two things:**

1. `driver` must obviously be an instance of WebDriver.
2. I would suggest not using the absolute XPath in general. Going with the relative XPath is less prone to be broken by small changes in the site structure. Click [here](https://www.lambdatest.com/blog/complete-guide-for-using-xpath-in-selenium-with-examples/) for a small guide to read through.